# How to send audio and video to database in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

i want to send audio and video lectures into the table of database...what is the code fortht

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't be storing that type of data in a database for the following reasons:

- Database size issues
- Performance issues

The best thing to do would:

- Upload the video to a private folder
- Create a database record linking to the physical location of the video file
- Create a script to serve the file if the user has permission to view it